# What is the right way set up address for form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I have controller `my_controller` and in it the action `my_action`. In `my_action` view I created a form and manually set this: `<%=form_tag('/photos/create') do%>`. When I send this form to this action in the `photos` controller, I'll get the error

```
No route matches [POST] "/photos/create"
```

(Obviously the action `create` exist in the `photos` controller)
My question is, why I am getting this error, when this action exist and, how can I fix it (what is the right way to set up address in the for manually)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your route is not correct.  The `create` action for photos should be to the `/photos` route instead with a `POST`.  You can verify this by running `rake routes` at your command line to get a list of all routes and how they are mapped to your controller actions.

Try this instead:

```
<%=form_tag(photos_path, :method => :post) do%>
```

For more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: :method => :post actually can be skipped as forms use it by default

Comment: @alony Agreed, but figured it would be useful to a new Rails user who may be confused by defaults